# Why does methods for wrapping element in Set/List/Map contains 'singleton' in name ?(java.util.Collections)

Tags: java, collections, singleton

I know if I had element and I want to get List/Set/Map with eith element only I should invoke :

`Collections.singleton()` /  `Collections.singletonList()` / `Collections.singletonMap()`

I don't understand why all these methods contains `singleton` in their names ?

I had assumption maybe it return same Collection for same object but this test shows that it is false

```
        Object o = new Object();
        System.out.println(Collections.singleton(o) == Collections.singleton(o));
```

output: false

For me singleton pattern forbid to create more than one element of concrete type and provided unify gateway for acces to this object.

please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a different meaning of the word "singleton" - it's not "the singleton pattern", it's "create a collection from a single item", that's all.

For example, from [`define:singleton`](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=define:singleton):

> a single person or thing of the kind under consideration.

Think of it this way: "singleton" is to "one thing" as "pair" is to "two things". So it wouldn't be entirely unnatural to have `Collections.pair(T t1, T t2)` in the same way.

Comment: +1 Someone who is not in a relationship could be called a "singleton"

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind these methods is that the **element** in the collection is a singular element, and will always be - you cannot remove it from the collection, nor can you add additional items to this collection.

Comment: Maybe you know way to achieve same functionality only for obtaining  mutable collection ?